# How to create a slot / signal for a button in a QMainWindow created by QT4 Designer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I want to have a python 2 program using qt4 which prints to terminal when a button is pressed in a QMainWindow.  How to create a slot / signal for a button in a QMainWindow created by QT4 Designer?

I have tried everything I can think of and I don't understand how to apply what I have found online to this problem. I am very new to python and it is likely the cause, please excuse me if this is obvious, but I'm very confused. The tutorials I've found are qt4 for C++, not python. If nothing else, at least the next person will be able to learn from this.

### Simplified Example Issue

**The error I get is:**

```
$ python ./main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 27, in <module>
    myGUI.connect(myGUI.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")),pushButtonCLICK)
AttributeError: 'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'pushButton'
```

**main.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

import PyQt4 
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QMainWindow

import gui

def pushButtonCLICK():
    print("you pressed the button! Yay! \n")


def main(args):
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    myGUI = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = gui.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(myGUI)
    myGUI.show()
    myGUI.connect(myGUI.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")),pushButtonCLICK)


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Design a `QMainWindow`in QT4 Designer, save as a ".ui" file and convert to python using:

```
pyuic4 -x ./test.ui -o ./gui.py
```

**gui.ui:**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>333</width>
    <height>245</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>85</width>
      <height>30</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>ClickHere</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>333</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**gui.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file './test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(333, 245)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 50, 85, 30))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 333, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ClickHere", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

import PyQt4 
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFormLayout, QMainWindow

import gui

def pushButtonCLICK():
    print("you pressed the button! Yay! \n")


def main(args):
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    myGUI = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = gui.Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(myGUI)
    myGUI.show()
    myGUI.connect(ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),pushButtonCLICK)


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: new style: change `myGUI.connect(ui.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),pushButtonCLICK)` to `ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(pushButtonCLICK)`